# How to setup reverse proxy?

Tags: proxy, vps

I am trying to setup a reverse proxy on a Ubuntu 12.04 VPS, that way I can protect a website from DDoS attacks. How can I do this? I found some tutorials online but they didn't seem to be what I was wanting.

Comment: a reverse proxy will not protect your web server from a ddos .

Comment: They can protect a web Server from attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend HAProxy.  Here is an article about it: [Use a load-balancer as a first row of defense against DDOS](http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/02/27/use-a-load-balancer-as-a-first-row-of-defense-against-ddos/) (HAProxy isn't just a load-balancer btw).

Their community site is here: http://www.haproxy.org/

Fair warning: the community version of HAProxy might not have as many features as the pay for version that they are likely mentioning the blog post.  We use stick tables to help protect us at our company.